# Proving that a sequence $\{\delta_n\} \in \ell_\infty^*$ has no weak-* convergent subsequence but has a weak-* convergent subnet

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-topology, nets

This is problem 12 in Reed & Simon's book on functional analysis.

Let $\{\delta_n\}$ be the sequence in $\ell_\infty^*$ such that
$$\delta_n\big(\{c_k\}_{k=1}^\infty\big) = c_n, \quad \forall \{c_k\}_{k=1}^\infty \in \ell_\infty.$$

Prove that $\{\delta_n\}$ has no weak-* convergent subsequence but has a weak-* convergent subnet.

I have been having a hard time getting started with this problem. There is already an answer posted on here for the subnet part of the problem ([Showing that a sequence in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})^*$ has a weak* convergent subnet](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787834/showing-that-a-sequence-in-ell-infty-mathbbn-has-a-weak-convergent-su)), but it uses filters which I am familiar with and which Reed and Simon avoid.

Does anyone have any tips on how to get started?

Comment: Given a subsequence $n_1,n_2,...$ define $x\in l^\infty$ to be $1$ on $n_k$ where $k$ is odd and zero otherwise. Then the $J(\delta_{n_k}) = \delta_{n_k}(x)$ has no limit.

Comment: @copper.hat Sorry could you explain why that subsequence having no limit for that particular choice of $x$ means any subsequence does not converge?

Comment: @CBBAM:  Convergence in the weak-* topology means that $\delta_{n_k}(x)$ must converge for any $x\in l^\infty$.  So it's enough to show divergence for a single $x$ to conclude the subsequence $\delta_{n_k}$ does not converge in the weak-* topology.  For the second part of your question, are you allowed to use the Banach–Alaoglu theorem and the result from general topology that in a compact space every net has a convergent subnet?

Comment: @JohnDoe Thank you, I understand for the first part now. For the second, I am familiar with Banach-Alaouglu and that result from general topology so they are okay to use.

Comment: @CBBAM:  Well, ok.  The $\delta_n$ all have norm $\le 1$ as functionals, so they're in the (closed) unit ball of $(l^\infty)^*$.  By Banach-Alaoglu, this unit ball is weak-* compact, a sequence is a kind of net, so it has a weak-* convergent subnet in same unit ball.

Comment: @JohnDoe Wow that a lot simpler than I had thought, thank you.